# Is there a way to store fetch in a function?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch

I have written this code in a react native project not in a component, I only have to store an array:

```
fetch(url, {})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
```

And everything works, but I would like to store what I printed. Instead using `console.log(data)` I have tried to use `const newData = data` but printing it I have noticed I have got `undefined`.

Comment: you need to use state, https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: I am testing that code stand alone, my goal is storing the array printed with `console.log(data)` in a variable

Answer (score 1):

To store the data, here's what I'd recommend.

First you can expand:

`.then(data => console.log(data))`

into:

```
.then((data) =>{
  console.log(data)
}
```

So we have more lines to write code on.
Because the `.then()` function is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Next we can initialize a variable at the top called `newData` and then set data equal to the `data` variable internally later. Also, I noticed you set your `newData` variable with the keyword `const`. `const` is an [immutable initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), meaning that it can only be set once and cannot be reset. Instead, use the `let` keyword. Our code looks like this now:

```
let newData;
fetch(url, {})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
       console.log(data)
       newData = data;
       console.log(newData)
     })
```

Now newData is stored there. If you want to `console.log` newData outside of the `.then()` function you will need to attach `async` to your `fetch()` function so it becomes :`async fetch()`. More on async [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the fetch method in react component then use the state to store the response and if you using fetch method in actions file you need to use [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), [redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) etc

Comment: I am not trying to use fetch methon in a react component. My goal is storing that array in a variable

Answer (score 0):

You still need to use State, like I said in comment

Here is an example

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
```

then on you fetch

```
fetch(url, {})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        data: data
      });
    });
)
```

Then `this.state.data` has what has been received from fetch